# Is there a way to get the Fourier transform / series of sinc(a*cos(t))?

Tags: fourier-analysis, trigonometric-integrals

I'm trying to solve a partial differential equation via spectral methods, but it hinges on my ability to get an accurate Fourier series (up to arbitrary order) of a pretty messy function.

$$\mathrm{sinc}(a \cos(\theta)) = \frac{\sin\big({a \cos(\theta)}\big)}{a \cos(\theta)}$$

With $\mathrm{sinc}(0) = 1$

I've had some preliminary success using the [Jacobi–Anger expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion) for $\sin(a \cos(x))$

$$\mathrm{sinc}(a \cos(\theta)) = \frac{-2}{a} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \mathrm{J}_{2n-1}(a) \sec(\theta) \cos\big( (2n-1)\theta \big)$$

Now, my hope was to find the Fourier series expansion for $\sec(\theta) \cos\big((2n-1)\theta\big)$, and then rearrange the summations to keep the Fourier series and compute the infinite Jacobi-Anger series. But so far I haven't had much luck.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Best,

Kevin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is even, so we only need the Fourier coefficients against the cosines.
$$\begin{split}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{in\theta} \frac{\sin(a\cos\theta)}{\cos\theta}d\theta &= \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{in\theta} \int_0^a\cos(u\cos\theta)du\,d\theta\\
&= \int_0^a\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{in\theta}  \cos(u\cos\theta)d\theta\, du\\
&= \int_0^a \frac 1 2  \int_{-\pi}^\pi \left(e^{i(n\theta +u\cos\theta)} + e^{i(n\theta -u\cos\theta)}\right)d\theta\,du\\
&= \frac 1 2\int_0^a  \left( e^{in\frac \pi 2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-i(n\theta +u\sin\theta)}d\theta + e^{in\frac \pi 2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-i(n\theta -u\sin\theta)}d\theta\right)du\\
&= \frac 1 2 \int_0^a  2\pi i^n \left(J_{-n}(-u)+ J_{-n}(u)\right)du
\end{split}$$
Since $J_n$ is odd if $n$ is odd, and is even otherwise, the integral above vanishes if $n$ is odd. Thus let's assume that $n=2m$ is even. In that case,  using the fact that $J_{-n}(x)=(-1)^n J_n(x)$,
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(2m\theta) \frac{\sin(a\cos\theta)}{\cos\theta}d\theta =
2\pi (-1)^{m}\int_0^a  J_{2m}(u)du$$
We conclude that $$\boxed{\frac{\sin(a\cos\theta)}{a\cos\theta} = \frac 1 a\int_0^aJ_0(u)du +\frac 2 {a}\sum_{m\geq 1}(-1)^m\left(\int_0^aJ_{2m}(u)du\right)\cos(2m\theta)}$$

The two seem to numerically [coincide](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/etw4iewtfk).

Defining
$$
I_{2m}(a) = \int_0^a J_{2m}(u)\, \mathrm{d} u,
$$
we obtain that
$$
I_{2m}(a) = I_0(a) - 2 \sum_{k=1}^m J_{2k-1}(a)
$$
and
$$
I_0(a) = aJ_0(a) + \frac{\pi a}{2} [J_1(a)\mathbf{H}_0(a) - J_0(a)\mathbf{H}_1(a)],
$$
where $\mathbf{H}_0(a)$ and $\mathbf{H}_1(a)$ are Struve functions of order 0 and 1, respectively.
By doing so, we do not need to perform the integral numerically.
The derivations can be seen in Sec. 1.1.7 of W. Rosenheinrich, Tables of Some Indefinite Integral of Bessel Functions of Integer Order, (2017).

Comment: Nice. I couldn't make any progress on that integral.

Comment: Thank you, I like your solution too. I wonder if we can relate them. For instance, I know we can express the primitive of $J_{2m}$ in terms of the $J_{2m+1}$'s and the primitive of $J_0$. Maybe this could lead to a formula similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks! That perfectly answers my question, I never would have thought to use the integral expression for $\mathrm{sinc}(a \cos(x))$.

Comment: The way I thought about it was: "What if I differentiate w.r.t $a$?"

Comment: Good solution! I added a method for solving the integral involving the Bessel functions.

Comment: Thank you! Good to know!

Answer (score 4):

I'll take you at your word when it comes to the Jacobi-Anger expansion. We are left to consider the Fourier coefficients of
$$f_m:[-\pi,\pi]\to\Bbb R \\ f_m(x)=\sec(x)\cos((2m-1)x)=\frac{\cos((2m-1)x)}{\cos(x)}$$
Clearly, all of the odd (sin-) coefficients are zero (since our function is even) so we need only consider the even coefficients,
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi f_m(x)\cos(nx)\mathrm dx$$
Here's what we will do. Recall the [Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html):

They are defined via the recurrence
$$T_{n}(x)=2x~T_{n-1}(x)-T_{n-2}(x)\tag{1}$$
With the starting values $T_0(x)=1~,~T_1(x)=x$ or equivalently by
$$T_n(x)=x~T_{n-1}(x)-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-T_{n-1}(x)^2)}\tag{2}$$
Explicitly, they can be given by the formula
$$T_n(x)=\frac{n}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^k\frac{(n-k-1)!}{k!(n-2k)!}2^kx^{n-2k}\tag{3}$$

They obey the useful identity
$$T_n(\cos \theta)=\cos(n\theta)\tag{4}$$

With that in mind,
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos\big((2m-1)x\big)\cos(nx)}{\cos(x)}\mathrm dx \\ =\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \frac{T_{2m-1}(\cos \theta)T_n(\cos \theta)}{\cos\theta}\mathrm d\theta$$
So it is natural to consider the variable substitution
$$x=\cos\theta \\ \theta=\arccos(x) \\ \mathrm d\theta=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
To yield
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{T_{2m-1}(x)}{x}T_n(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm dx\tag{5}$$
This looks *so close* to the orthogonality identity
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1 T_{m}(x)T_n(x)\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm dx=\begin{cases}\delta_{m,n}& m\neq 0~\text{or}~n\neq 0 \\ 2 & m=n=0\end{cases}$$

So we consider the family of integrals
$$a_{m,n}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{T_{2m-1}(x)}{x}T_{n}(x)\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\tag{6}$$
With $m\in\Bbb N$ and $n\in\Bbb N_0$.

First, a lemma.

> **Lemma:** Let $m\in\Bbb N$. Then the Chebyshev polynomial $T_{2m-1}$ has no constant term, in other words, $T_{2m-1}(0)=0$.

**Proof:** We proceed with induction. Clearly $T_{2\cdot 1-1}(x)=T_1(x)=x$ so $T_{2m-1}(0)=0$ for $m=1$. Then, using $(1)$,
$$T_{2(m+1)-1}(x)=T_{2m+1}(x)=2x~T_{2m}(x)-T_{2m-1}(x)$$
So,
$$T_{2(m+1)-1}(0)=2\cdot 0\cdot T_{2m}(0)-T_{2m-1}(0) \\ =-T_{2m-1}(0) \\ =-0=0.$$
QED. What this means is that $T_{2m-1}(x)/x$ is still a polynomial. Now, if we could *somehow* write $T_{2m-1}(x)/x$ as some combination of other Chebyshev polynomials, we could reduce $(6)$ to a linear combination of integrals we already know via the orthogonality identity. *Somehow*, actually, we can. Via simple experimentation with Mathematica, I found the following amazing identity:
$$\frac{T_{2m-1}(x)}{x}=(-1)^m +2\sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^{k+1}T_{2(m-k)}(x)\tag{7}$$
Don't ask me how, because I'm honestly amazed at it too.
We prove this recurrence below, using induction. First, the base case.
$$\frac{T_{2\cdot 1-1}(x)}{x}=1 \\ (-1)^1+2\sum_{k=1}^1 (-1)^{k+1}T_{2(1-k)}(x)=-1+2T_0(x)=-1+2=1.$$
Now we induct. Substitute $m+1$:
$$\frac{T_{2(m+1)-1}(x)}{x}=\frac{T_{2m+1}(x)}{x}$$
Now use $(1)$:
$$\frac{T_{2m+1}(x)}{x}=\frac{1}{x}\left(2xT_{2m}(x)-T_{2m-1}(x)\right) \\ =2T_{2m}(x)-\frac{T_{2m-1}(x)}{x} \\ = 2T_{2m}(x)-(-1)^{m}-2\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^{k+1}T_{2(m-k)}(x) \\ =2T_{2m}(x)+(-1)^{m+1}+2\sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^{k+1+1}T_{2(m+1-(k+1))}(x)$$
Now change the index in the sum $j=k+1$ and add and subtract the $j=1$ term:
$$\frac{T_{2m+1}(x)}{x}=2T_{2m}(x)+(-1)^{m+1}+2\sum_{j=2}^{m+1}(-1)^{j+1}T_{2(m+1-j)}(x) \\ =\color{red}{2T_{2m}(x)}+(-1)^{m+1}\color{red}{-2\cdot(-1)^{1+1}T_{2(m+1-1)}(x)}+2\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+1}T_{2(m+1-j)}(x) \\ =(-1)^{m+1}+2\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j+1}T_{2(m+1-j)}(x)$$
Which is exactly equation $(7)$ but with $m+1$ instead of $m$ and the summation index $j$ instead of $k$, which obviously doesn't matter. That means our formula is proved. What this means, going back to $(6)$, is that
$$a_{m,n}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1T_n(x)\left((-1)^m+2\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^{k+1}T_{2(m-k)}(x)\right)\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

$$a_{m,n}=\begin{matrix}(-1)^m\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1 T_n(x)\cdot 1~\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\+2\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^{k+1}\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1 T_n(x)T_{2(m-k)}(x)\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\end{matrix}$$
Substitute $1=T_0(x)$:
$$a_{m,n}=\begin{matrix}(-1)^m\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1 T_n(x)T_0(x)\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\+2\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^{k+1}\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1 T_n(x)T_{2(m-k)}(x)\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\end{matrix}$$
And finally use orthogonality. If $n=0$ then
$$a_{m,0}=(-1)^m\cdot 2+2\cdot (-1)^{m+1}\cdot 2 \\ =2(-1)^m-4(-1)^m \\ =-2(-1)^m=2(-1)^{m+1}$$
And if $n\neq 0$ then
$$a_{m,n}=2\sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^{k+1}\delta_{n,2(m-k)}$$
Hence
$$f_m(x)=\frac{\cos\big((2m-1)x\big)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{a_{m,0}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{m,n}\cos(nx) \\ =(-1)^{m+1}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(nx)\sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^{k+1}\delta_{n,2(m-k)}$$

We immediately realize that $a_{m,n}=0$ whenever $n$ is odd. (Because $2(m-k)$ can never be odd.) This allows us to equivalently consider
$$\delta_{2n,2(m-k)}=\delta_{n,m-k}$$
And write
$$f_m(x)=(-1)^{m+1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(2nx)A_{m,n}$$
Where
$$A_{m,n}=2\sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^{k+1}\delta_{n,m-k}$$

We also realize that this sum is finite. Whenever $n\geq m$, $\delta_{n,m-k}$ is always $0$, since $m-k<m\leq n$, and correspondingly $A_{m,n}=0$. Hence
$$f_m(x)=(-1)^{m+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\cos(2nx) A_{m,n}$$
The only possibly nonzero term in the summation for $A_{m,n}$ is when
$$n=m-k\implies k=m-n$$
Therefore $A_{m,n}=2(-1)^{m-n+1}$ in our summation range. Thus, finally,
$$\boxed{f_m(x)=\frac{\cos\big((2m-1)x\big)}{\cos(x)}=(-1)^{m+1}+2\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}(-1)^{m-n+1}\cos(2nx)}\tag{8}$$

You can check this numerically [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/anvublr3ar).

---

Putting this together towards your original question, this would seem to suggest that, in the interval $\theta\in[-\pi,\pi]$ that
$$\operatorname{sinc}(t\cos x)=\frac{-2}{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n J_{2n-1}(t)\left((-1)^{n+1}+2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-k+1}\cos(2k x)\right)$$
Splitting up the sum,
$$\operatorname{sinc}(t\cos x)=\frac{2}{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_{2n-1}(t)-\frac{4}{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nJ_{2n-1}(t)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-k+1}\cos(2kx)$$
Finally since $(-1)^{2n}=1$,
$$\boxed{\operatorname{sinc}(t\cos x)=\frac{2}{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_{2n-1}(t)-\frac{4}{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_{2n-1}(t)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k-1}\cos(2kx)}\tag{9}$$
The last sum is in fact known,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k-1}\cos(2kx)=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1+(-1)^n\big(\cos(2nx)+
\sin(2nx)\tan(x)\big)\bigg)$$
So another way of writing the same thing is
$$\boxed{\operatorname{sinc}(t\cos x)=\frac{-2}{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n J_{2n-1}(t)\big(\cos(2nx)+\sin(2nx)\tan(x)\big)}\tag{10}$$
Not exactly a Fourier series, but this representation appears to [converge very quickly](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6ladkqkzzy).

Comment: Thanks for this analysis! I went through the Chebyshev polynomial rabbit hole as well, but I got stumped at proving the Eq. 7 and then utilizing that. This is really elegant!