# I found a reduction formula for odd-order Chebyshev polynomials. Is it new? Are there other ones like it?

Tags: chebyshev-polynomials, reduction-formula

While working on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4522542/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-fourier-transform-series-of-sincacost/4522680#4522680), I miraculously found (and proved) the following reduction formula:
$$T_{2n-1}(x)=(-1)^nx+2x\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}T_{2(n-k)}(x)$$
This basically allows us to express an odd-order Chebyshev polynomial as a sort of combination of the even order polynomials below it. My questions:

- Is this formula new? I looked at DLMF, functions.wolfram.com, Wolfram mathworld, Wikipedia, etc and didn't find it. Is it worth publication?
- Are there other formulas like it? Like, can we express the *even* order Chebyshev polynomials as a combination of the *odd* order polynomials below it?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that a trivial consequence of $T_{n+1}(x)=2x\,T_{n}(x)-T_{n-1}(x)$, with the same decomposition applied repeatedly to the last term until nothing is left?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Can you explain? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Can you apply this to $T_{2n-1}(x)$ as the LHS?